# How to manage route in React and symfony project?

Tags: reactjs, symfony, react-router-dom, vite

I use React to a page in symfony with vite:

This is the base:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
           and uncomment the following Encore helpers to start using Symfony UX #}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('images/Logo 2.png') }}">
        <meta
        name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ vite_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        
        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ vite_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Reseau Sociaux{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div id="app"></div>
  
{% endblock %}
```

This is the controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/reseau-sociaux", name="reseau-sociaux_home")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
     */
    public function reseauSociaux(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('reseauSociaux/reseauSociaux.html.twig');
    }
```

And this is my react:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Actualite from './pageActualite/Actualite'
import './styles/app.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProfilUser from "./otherPages/ProfilUser/ProfilUser";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="reseau-sociaux" element={<Actualite />}/>
                <Route path="/reseau-sociaux/profil" element={<ProfilUser />}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
const rootElement = document.querySelector('#app');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(<App />);
```

The problem is the **route**, react-router-dom is working well but if I refresh the page the error is: no route found, an error from symfony. For example if I refresh the /reseau-sociaux/profil page, I get the error because there is no route /reseau-sociaux/profil in my symfony.

I have others twig pages too but they work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure... it is the symfony route that not match if you extend the route from `/reseau-sociaux` to `/reseau-sociaux/profil`. You must symfony tell that your route can have sub pathes.

You can change the route parameters to match on sub pathes like

```php
/**
 * @Route("/reseau-sociaux/{sub}", name="reseau-sociaux_home", requirements={"sub"=".+"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 */
public function reseauSociaux(Request $request, ?string $sub = null)
{
    return $this->render('reseauSociaux/reseauSociaux.html.twig');
}
```